# Problema con ejercicio de ajedrez en java

Tags: java, algoritmos, matrices

El objetivo del programa es imprimir un tablero de ajedrez, con casillas B (blancas) y N (negras), pedir una fila y una columna y establecer un alfil ahí.

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero el problema viene cuando hay que modificar el tablero con asteriscos en las casillas donde se pueda mover el alfil (en diagonal):

```
        B * B N B * B N
        N B * B * B N B
        B N B A B N B N
        N B * B * B N B
        B * B N B * B N
        * B N B N B * B
        B N B N B N B *
        N B N B N B N B
```

El profesor se ha saltado este problema, entonces recurro a este foro.
¿Cómo lo plantearíais?
Código:

```
int posicion=8*(fila-1)+columna;

  for(int i=1;i<=64;i++) {

        if(i%2!=0){
           if(i==posicion){
              System.out.print("A ");
              continue;
           }
           System.out.print("B ");
        }else{
           if(i==posicion){
              System.out.print("A ");
              continue;
           }
           System.out.print("N ");
        }

     if(i%8==0){
        System.out.println();
     }

  }
```

No he dado matrices todavía. Gracias

[EDIT]
Sólo valen movimientos válidos, de acuerdo con el movimiento real del alfil.

Comment: Buen días MigHc, solo la siguiente duda, se pueden llenar todas las diagonales con asteriscos, o hay que poner solo movimientos válidos. Sería bueno que agregues esa información al problema

Comment: ¿qué has intentado hacer?¿qué problema te has encontrado?

Comment: Necesito representar el movimiento del alfil mediante asteriscos (en todas las casillas donde se puede mover el alfil en un movimiento). El problema es que no se como enfocarlo, no encuentro una generalización para cualquier punto del tablero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres que tu alfil se coloque en la posición `[x1 ; y1]`, entonces tienes que completar con asteriscos todas las posiciones `[x2 ; y2]` que cumplan con la condición de que:

1. `X1 != X2 y Y1 != Y2`
2. `| X1 - X2 | = | Y1 - Y2 |`

Creo que el siguiente código puede ayudarte:

```
public static int mod(int x) { return (x < 0)?-x:x; } 

int x, y; //Posicion del alfil

for(int i=1;i<=8;i++) {
    for(int j=1;j<=8;j++)
        if(i == x && j == y)
            System.out.print("A ");
        else if(mod(i - x) == mod(j - y))
            System.out.print("* ");
        else if((i + j) % 2 == 0)
            System.out.println("B ");
        else
            System.out.println("N ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Ok {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dbjt(2, 3);
    }

    public static void dbjt(int f, int c) {
        int a = f - c;
        int b = f + c;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                if (i == f && j == c) {
                    System.out.print("A");
                } else if (i - j == a || i + j == b) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print((i + j) % 2 == 0 ? "B" : "N");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

/*

Me recordó el problema de las 8 reinas y como un alfil se mueve parcialmente como una reina, la formula que ocupas es similar a la necesaria para representar el primer problema. Puedes ver la sección "Planteamiento del Problema" en el enlace a la wiki que te dejo; basicamente una posición está en diagonal con otra si el resultado de fila menos columna o fila más columna es el mismo en ambas. Saludos desde México.
[enlace](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_de_las_ocho_reinas)

*/

Comment: Por favor explica el código que has escrito. Puedes hacerlo agregando información en la respuesta o en forma de comentarios en el mismo código.

Comment: El tablero que presentas no es correcto: los recuadros negros y blancos están intercalados, tu has ido generando filas sin variar entre ellas, por tanto las columnas son o blancas o negras. Por lo demás creo que está bien. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola!

Pude hacerlo, el código es sencillo. Te explico la lógica:

Cuando posicionamos el alfil (ej. 2,2), podemos marcar un punto principal de la diagonal sumando a dicha posición un "uno", esto nos quedaría como 3,3.

```
B N B N
B A B N
B N * N
B N B N
```

Así que si hacemos un FOR (`pos1 + i` `pos2 + i`), la diagonal se va a formar automáticamente, teniendo en cuenta que la suma de la posición 1 y 2 no puede ser mayor a la longitud de la matriz (osea, si la matriz es de 4 x 4, la `pos1 + i < 4 && pos2 + i < 4`).

Esto nos quedaria tal que así ahora:

```
B N B N
B A B N
B N * N
B N B *
```

Una vez ya nos hemos percatado de esto solamente queda "jugar": Si hacemos la inversa de lo que hemos hecho (`pos1 - i >= 0 && pos2 - i >= 0`) nos quedaría así:

```
* N B N
B A B N
B N B N
B N B N
```

Si hacemos un mixto... (`pos1 - i >= 0 && pos2 + i < 8` y `pos1 + i< 8 && pos2 - i >= 0`), nos daría las otras dos diagonales.

Así que si dentro de un for metemos 4 `IF` con las condiciones explicadas... ¡El ejercicio está resuelto!

Os dejo mi código, los `println` y los comentarios están escritos en catalán, no os ralléis :')

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int op = 0, op1 = 0, k = 0, p =  0;
    String[][] a = new String[8][8];
    // BLANC NEGRE
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0) {
                a[i][j] = "B";
            } else if (i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 == 0) {
                a[i][j] = "B";
            } else {
                a[i][j] = "N";
            }

        }
    }

    // MOSTRAR
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf(a[i][j] + "       ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    // PREGUNTAR
    System.out.printf("En quina fila vols posar l'alfil: ");
    op = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("En quina columna vols posar l'alfil: ");
    op1 = sc.nextInt();

    op = op - 1;
    op1 = op1 - 1;

    //SUBSTITUIR
    a[op][op1] = "A";

    //MOSTRAR
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf(a[i][j] + "       ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");

    //DIAGONALS
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {

        if (op+i < 8 && op1+i <8) {
            a[op+i][op1+i] = "*";
        }

        if (op-i >= 0 && op1-i >= 0) {
            a[op-i][op1-i]="*";
        }

        if (op+i < 8 && op1-i >= 0) {
            a[op+i][op1-i] = "*";
        }

        if (op-i >= 0 && op1+i <8) {
            a[op-i][op1+i] = "*";
        }

    }

    //MOSTRAR
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf(a[i][j] + "       ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```